# How programmatically to know if node of treeview has children (kendoui treeview for angular)?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, nodechildren

Please, let me know in what way we can programmatically know if node in kendo treeview structure has childrens ?

Need to apply corresponding class for nodes which has children...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/node-template/). They use `ngClass` in the node template to set the icon displayed on the node.

You can also check if a node has children by using the `hasChildren(item)` method of the TreeView.

Comment: 1) They use ngClass inside of ng-template to define what kind of icon to show. In my case I need to apply class for element                                            
<li class="k-item ng-tns-c0-1" kendotreeviewitem="" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="false" aria-checked="false" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1" data-treeindex="0_0">    (from devTools)                                               which is node.For that moment I don't imagine how it may be done using kendo's api.

Comment: 2) they use such input parameters for inner logic of component as I it imagine: [hasChildren]="hasChildren" <-- use fetchChildren function to check if node has children. My goal is to set special class or attribute for node(li.k-item) which has children. For that time it's a secret for me how it may be implemented using standard kendo's api.

Comment: Why do you need to apply a class specifically on the `li` itself?

Comment: Because I need to customize kendo's treeview for compliance to required design and for that purposes I need to apply for items (`li`) special class if they have children.

Comment: You don't have to apply the class directly to the `li` elements, you can do it the way they did it in the demo. Why add the class directly to the `li`?